# update is not defined?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm  trying to make a moving object on canvas, but each time the set interval goes off it gives me the error: "update is not defined" even though update's definition is right there before init. How do I get set interval to call update correctly?

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">  
    <head>  
          <meta charset="utf-8">  
          <title>Test</title>  
          <meta name="description" content="An HTML5 Test">  
          <meta name="author" content="William Starkovich">  
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                var angle = 0.0;
                var increment = 0.1;

                function incrementAngle(angle, increment){
                    angle += increment;

                    if(angle > Math.PI * 2)
                        angle -= (Math.PI * 2);
                }

                function update(angle, increment){
                    incrementAngle(angle, increment);

                    //get a reference to the canvas
                    var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
                    //draw a circle
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(20, 20, 15, angle, angle + Math.PI, true);
                    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.closePath();
                }

                function init(angle, increment){  
                  update(angle, increment) 
                  setInterval("update(angle, increment)",1000);  
                } 

                init(angle, increment);

            });
          </script>    
    </head>  
    <body>  
         <canvas id="canvas" width="800px" height="100px">
        <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
        </canvas>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be looking to use global variables, so why not go all the way?

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8L62c/3/

```
var angle = 0.0;
var increment = 0.1;

function incrementAngle() {
    angle += increment;
    if (angle > Math.PI * 2) angle -= (Math.PI * 2);
}

function update() {
    incrementAngle();

    //get a reference to the canvas
    var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");
    //draw a circle
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(20, 20, 15, angle, angle + Math.PI, true);
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function init() {
    update();
    setInterval(update, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    init();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use strings in `eval` because they are executed in global scope and your function is defined in the document.ready handler.  Use an anonymous function if you want to provide arguments:

```
setInterval(function() { update(angle, increment); } ,1000);
```

Comment: Won't this keep passing the same angle and increment to `update` over and over again?

Comment: @mblase75 No it won't. It calls the anonymous function each time and since it's passing the value of a variable, if those variable change the value it will pass will change.

Comment: There are two problems - the scope of `update` and the scope of the variables.  The `update` scope problem is fixed by changing the `eval`ed code to a closure.  The variable scoping problem is fixed with mblase75's solution which removes the parameters from the function signatures.  The OP was only changing the local copies of the global variables, not the global variables themselves.